# Multiple Terraform environments failure

Tags: terraform

I am currently building a Terraform script to build resources in multiple environments.  I'd like to have a nonprod-1 environment as well as a nonprod-2 environment.

I was able to build nonprod-1.  I then also successfully built nonprod-2.

I keep the terraform.tfstate files for each in a bucket named:

```
mybucket
  nonprod-1/terraform.tfstate
  nonprod-2/terraform.tfstate
```

and have a provider_config.tf file containing:

```
terraform {
  backend "s3" {
    bucket = "mybucket"
//    Comment out key.  Enter as a command line parm in the init statement
//    key    = "nonprod-1/terraform.tfstate"
    region = "us-east-1"
  }
}
```

Next, I wanted to go back to nonprod-1, having made some changes.  So, I ran the command line:

```
terraform init -backend-config="key=nonprod-1/terraform.tfstate"
```

This resulted in the questions:

```
 Do you want to copy the state from "s3"?
  Would you like to copy the state from your prior backend "s3" to the
  newly configured "s3" backend? If you're reconfiguring the same backend,
  answering "yes" or "no" shouldn't make a difference. Please answer exactly
  "yes" or "no".

  Enter a value:
```

I answered **yes**

Next, I got the prompt:

```
Do you want to copy state from "s3" to "s3"?
  Pre-existing state was found in "s3" while migrating to "s3". An existing
  non-empty state exists in "s3". The two states have been saved to temporary
  files that will be removed after responding to this query.

  One ("s3"): C:\Users\foo\AppData\Local\Temp\terraform757778187\1-s3.tfstate
  Two ("s3"): C:\Users\foo\AppData\Local\Temp\terraform757778187\2-s3.tfstate

  Do you want to copy the state from "s3" to "s3"? Enter "yes" to copy
  and "no" to start with the existing state in "s3".
```

Again I answered **yes**

Next, I ran my apply command.  Instead of updating the nonprod-1 environment, it attempted to replace all the nonprod-2 resources with nonprod-1 resources.

Questions:

1. Why did it update nonprod-2 rather than switching over to
       nonprod-1 (I assumed the init should have pointed to the nonprod-1 state file)
2. What does the first prompt mean?  I assume I **do** want to copy the state             from "s3" as that is the purpose of remote state.
3. What does the second prompt mean?  It sounds like it is asking if I want to             overwrite the existing tfstate file?  Why does it ask if I want to copy from "s3" to "s3" though?  And, why does it mention finding two files?
4. Finally, now that everything is buggered up, what is the best way to
   recover?  I attempted to destroy everything, but a bunch of resources
   were left created.  Subsequent destroy's didn't destroy anything else.  Can I just delete the state files in S3 and have
   everything get recreated?  If so, I guess that means I have to
   manually delete all the remaining resources?

Comment: Some further testing found that if I answered NO to the first prompt, I would have been fine.  That renders the second prompt moot as it doesn't then appear.

Comment: I still am looking for a way of cleaning up the mess left behind.  It appears manually deleting everything from the console OR doing a terraform import would solve the problem.  The first method would be much faster than having to import each remaining resource.

Comment: I had the same problem and same bad impact the first time. Choosing "No" 2nd time around did the trick without damaging the state.